# Linking A Selected Item in a Tree View to a Data Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, treeview

I have created a treeview using [Josh Smith's MVVM model](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode), but I want to create an adjacent datagrid that changes to represent the component selected in the treeview.

However, I can't figure out how to bind the datagrid's item source to the selected treeviewitem, since I can't get to the component that's selected in the treegrid.

```
<Window x:Class="TreeDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
    
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView Name = "myTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedComponent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is my XAML.

```
namespace TreeDataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        readonly AllComponentsTreeViewModel allComponentsTreeViewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Get the sample components data

            Component demoComponent = new Component();
            Component demoChild1 = new Component();
            Component demoChild2 = new Component();
            Component demoSubChild = new Component();

            demoComponent.Name = "RootBoy";
            demoChild1.Name = "Child1";
            demoChild2.Name = "Child2";
            demoSubChild.Name = "SubChild";

            

            DataGridProps data1 = new DataGridProps(23, "demo", false);
            DataGridProps data2 = new DataGridProps(25, "is", true);

            demoComponent.Data = new List<Object>() { data2, data2 };
            demoChild1.Data = new List<Object>() { data1, data2 };
            demoChild2.Data = new List<Object>() { data1, data2 };
            demoSubChild.Data = new List<Object>() { data2, data1 };

            demoChild1.SubComponents = new List<Component>() { demoSubChild };
            demoComponent.SubComponents = new List<Component>(){ demoChild1, demoChild2 };

            allComponentsTreeViewModel = new AllComponentsTreeViewModel(demoComponent);

            base.DataContext = allComponentsTreeViewModel;
           
        }

        
        
    }
}
```

is my main Window.
I have a SelectedComponent getter in my allComponentsTreeViewModel, but I don't know how to retrieve the selected TreeViewItem, and more importantly, how to update SelectedComponent when a new TreeViewItem is selected.
[Here's a mockup of what I want, with a different data grid when a new treeviewitem is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpd8m.png)
Am I going about this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

In your TreeView you should bind the SelectedItem property.

```
<TreeView Selecteditem="{Binding SelectedItemInTreeView}" ...
```

and then use it as the ItemsSource in your DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemInTreeView.MyCollectionProperty }" ...
```

In your ViewModel you should raise the PropertyChangedEvent when the SelectedItemInTreeView changes so that the DataGrid ItemsSource is refreshed when the selection changes in the TreeView.